# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentiment_mod'

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am using nltk sentiment_mod but python is throwing module not found error

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import sentiment_mod as sen_mod
```

the error is

```
ModuleNotFoundError                
      Traceback (most recent call last)
      2 from tweepy import OAuthHandler
      3 from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
----> 4 import nltk.sentiment_mod as sen_mod
      5 import json
      6 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentiment_mod'
```

Comment: what is `sentiment_mod` can you give the link of docs ?

Comment: is it not in docs but in this tutorial  https://pythonprogramming.net/twitter-sentiment-analysis-nltk-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's no such module in `ntlk`.](https://www.nltk.org/py-modindex.html#cap-s) Judging by the name, it's some private modification of `ntlk.sentiment`. Consult wherever you got this code from how to use it. Maybe there are some additional requirements, or it's simply obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

"sentiment_mod" seems to be a file name for a sentiment analysis module that were created before and is called here in your code.
A good example for this can be: 
https://pythonprogramming.net/sentiment-analysis-module-nltk-tutorial/